# How to filter on a foreign key that is grouped?

Tags: django, django-orm

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Result(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    outcome = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Sql:

```
select * from person as p
inner join (
   select person_id, max(time) as max_time, outcome from result
   group by person_id
) r on p.id = r.person_id
where r.result in (2, 3)
```

I'm wanting to get the all person records where the last result outcome was either a 2 or 3. I added the raw sql above to further explain.

I looked at using a subquery to filter person records that have a matching result id

```
sub_query = Result.objects.values("person_id").annotate(max_time=Max("time"))
```

however using values strips out the other fields.

Ideally I'd be able to do this in one person queryset but I don't think that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a person may have multiple result records and I only want to check the last record, A [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) was the only way I could find to do this

```
last_result = Subquery(
    Result.objects.filter(person_id=OuterRef("pk")).order_by("-time").values("result")[:1]
)

people = Person.objects.all().annotate(max_time=Max("result__time"), current_result=last_result).filter(current_result__in=[2,3)
```

First I create a sub query that will return the last result record. Then I add this as a field in the people query so that I can filter on that for only results with 2 or 3.

This was it will only return person records where the current result is a 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

The below query exclude all persons whose marks not equal to 2 OR 3, then it sorts the results in time descending order (latest will be on top) and finally get the details for person ...

```
from django.db.models import Q

results = Results.objects.filter(Q(outcome=3) | Q(outcome=2)).order_by('-time').values('person')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: A number of person records will have the last result as another value (i.e 1), in this case they should be excluded. Only records where the last record is a 2 or 3 should be returned.

Comment: Brief explanation has been added, if you find answer is helpful then don't hesitate to upvote, thanks in advance!!